# Why can't I access the elements of my NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, indexing, nsmutablearray

I declared arrays a,b,c and d as properties in my interface class and initialized them like this:

```
[self setPatternA:[[NSMutableArray init] initWithArray:@[@0,@0,@1,@1,@2,@2]]];
[self setPatternB:[[NSMutableArray init] initWithArray:@[@3,@4,@4,@5,@5,@3]]];
[self setPatternC:[[NSMutableArray init] initWithArray:@[@3,@3,@4,@4,@5,@5]]];
[self setPatternD:[[NSMutableArray init] initWithArray:@[@0,@1,@1,@2,@2,@0]]];
```

and now I'm trying to access them like this:

```
NSInteger a=[patternA objectAtIndex:3];
NSLog(@"pattern a: %ld", (long)a);
```

but when i print what this returns it isn't the value that I'm expecting. I am also getting a "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') with an expression of type 'id'.

Also, if someone could explain what a 'long' is, that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't put integers, or `NSInteger`s, into the array, but objects, i.e. instances of `NSNumber`.

```
NSNumber *number = patternA[3];
long a = number.longValue;
```

will give give you correct value.

This is called boxing / unboxing - putting plain values into objects. So what you were dumping was more or less the address of the containing object.

Comment: Is there a way to store ints in an array in objective-c?

Comment: Not with the standard implementation of NSArray. Of course you can use plain c arrays (int []) with all their (dis)advantages, or resort to Obj-C++ and use something like vector<int>. I'd only do so if you find that the stock NSArray is not good enough for your performance/storage needs. In most cases, it's just fine and much preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Your arrays contain `NSNumber` - `@1` is a `NSNumber` Literal. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

a `long` can hold a larger number than an `int`, but also takes up more bytes in memory http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/objective-c-succinctly-data-types--mobile-21986